# How to config RequireJS shim dependencies just in time?

Tags: dependencies, requirejs, shim

I want to load some non-AMD modules (and CSSs via require-css), that depend on each other (my case is CodeMirror and some of its addons, but the question is generic); but I need this only in some scenarios, and not in other ones. That's why I don't want to pollute main `require.config` call with all known combinations of shim dependencies.

When I want to include the set, I include `codemirror_set` in the list of dependencies, and the `codemirror_set.js` itself contains just the simple

```
define([
  'lib/codemirror/js/codemirror',
  '...', // some addons and css's
]);
```

The problem is, those dependencies in `define` depend on each other, but when I prepend `require.config({shim:{...}});` before this `define`, it is not honoured, If I include it in the main `require.config` where I map paths etc. it works, but it is reused and as I wrote I do not want to pollute it with all possibilities.

How can I include shim dependencies just-in-time, before `define` that contains interdependent dependencies?

P.S.: It works even if I include the shim deps config in the file that requires the `codemirror_set` but there are more of them, so it would need to be replicated to every one of them. I'd like to have it defined just once.

Answer (score 0):

This code does what I understand you want to do: add a shim at run time. This is the `modA` module. By the time it is loaded there is no way to access `modB`. The `require.config` call adds the configuration necessary to access it and then loads it:

```
define(function () {

require.config({
    paths: {
        'modB': "../others/modB"
    },
    shim: {
        'modB': {exports: "value"}
    }
});

require(['modB'], function (modB) {
    console.log('loaded modB');
    console.log("modB's value", modB);
});

});
```

Comment: But this `modA` cannot be used as a dependency that ensure `modB` is loaded. I do not need to 'just load it some time later', but to define 'modA` to depend on 'modB' and others, while shimming their interdependencies just in time.

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution: if I want to define `modA` so that it depends on `modB` and `modC` and I need to set up shim dependency between `modB` and `modC` just-in-time, I need to split the definition in two files:

`modA.js`:

```
require.config({shim:{
  modB: { deps: [ 'modC' ] }
});

define(['./modA-inner'], function (x) { return x; });
```

`modA-inner.js`:

```
define(['modB', 'modC'],
  ...
);
```

The configuration set in `modA.js` is honoured inside `modA-inner.js`, so dependencies are resolved as they should. Though it need one more loading roundtrip.